# what is the best way populate the status bar of non- parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbar

How do i to access or update the controls of non-parent or non-mdi form from another form in C#.

IF yes, the I have a form - **Form1** and button on it. When i click button, new form - **Form**2 opens which is not child form.What i want to try is when i do some activity on **Form2**, some information should be displayed on status-bar of **Form1**.

If sample available it will be good.

Thanks,

Comment: Add public properties/methods to do that; alternative (but bad practice) is to make corresponding StatusBars public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mediator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMediator.aspx) basically you have to create both form sharing the same mediator object.

Update sample code

```
public class SimpleMediator{

    public Form1 MainForm {get; set;}

    public void DisplayStatus(string message){
        MainForm.StatusBar.Text = message;
    }
}

public class Form2 : Form{

    public SimpleMediator Mediator {get; set;}

    //...
}
```

then when you open Form2

```
    public void OpenSubForm(){
        var mediator = new Mediator{
            MainForm = this;
        };
        var f2 = new Form2(){
            Mediator = mediator;
        };
        f2.Show();
    }
```

Now you can access `Mediator.DisplayStatus()` method inside Form2

Comment: any example available similarly

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a event in Form2 to notify others that certain action is triggered:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public class StatusChangedArgs : EventArgs
    {
        // Put useful information here which would be retrieved from Form1
    }

    public event EventHandler<StatusChangedArgs> StatusChanged;

    private void OnStatusChanged()
    {
        var handler = StatusChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new StatusChangedArgs());
    }

    // Call OnStatusChanged in other Form2's functions, e.g. button click ...
}
```

Then when Form1 creates Form2, you can register Form1 as a listener to the Form2's event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.StatusChanged += form2_StatusChanged;
    }

    void form2_StatusChanged(object sender, Form2.StatusChangedArgs e)
    {
        // Update Form1's status bar here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit the Form2's constructor and add a new the Form1's reference:**

```
    public Form2(Form1 form1Para)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This is the Form1 reference
        Form1 form1 = form1Para;
    }
```

**Then edit Form1, where you have the method opening the new Form2:**

```
        // Give Form1 in the constructor (this <- the Form1)
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that Form2 raises an event that Form1 handles.  The event args can contain the data or Form1 can get the data from a property of Form2.

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html